# accept="video/mp4" accept webm files also

Tags: html, video

I want to allow user to upload only mp4 videos. So I am using accept="video/mp4" in my input element. Following is my input element:

```
 <input id="chatFileUpload" type="file" style="display: none"  accept="image/*,video/mp4,audio/*"/>
```

But it is also accepting webm video formats. How can I prevent it accepting webm files?

But it accept only mp4 when I remove image/* and audio/* from accept as follows:

```
<input id="chatFileUpload" type="file" style="display: none"  accept="video/mp4"/>
```

Comment: WebM can be audio too.

Comment: Yes my bad. Embarrassing mistake :( I just realized and was going to comment this. Anyways Thanks.